# fetching data from two tables and pass it to a list - hibernate and spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I want to fetch data from two tables using hibernate and concat the result into a single list. I have been on this for days now but seem to be no head way. Here is a snippet of the two tables returning a list.

```
List<Records> rec = recService.getAllRecords();
        List<Data> rec2 = dataService.getAllDataRecords();
```

My challenge at the moment is to pass the two search result into a single list. Any assistance and idea is much appreciated. Kindly assist

**EDITED**

```
List<Object> combined = new ArrayList<>();
        combined.addAll(rec);
        combined.addAll(rec2);


        for (Object string : combined) {

            //I am getting error below in calling methods from the combined arraylist   
            returnMatchName.add(string.getFirstname() + " " + string.getLastname() );
```

Comment: You calling the same method `getAllRecords` twice?

Comment: check edits....tnx

Comment: Maybe I miserunderstood the issue but... I would do something like this: `List<Object> total = new ArrayList<Object>()` and then `total.addAll(rec);` and `total.addAll(rec2);`

Comment: How do I get the method from the total arraylist... eg total.getName

Comment: @Kingston you are changing the question by adding another question inside. Please, move your other question somewhere else (and you can mark one of the working answers as correct)

Comment: Ok. Thank you but I just want to be clear on the solutions put forward to me

Comment: I have accepted one of the amswers but I dont see why I am getting a downvote on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a couple ways.  If `Records` and `Data` share a common interface, say `Record`, then this will work.

java 8:

```
List<Record> combined = Stream.concat(rec.stream(), rec2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

java 7 and below:

```
List<Record> combined = new ArrayList<>();
combined.addAll(rec);
combined.addAll(rec2);
```

If they do not implement a common interface, your `List` will have to be a list of Object

Comment: They do not share common interface...

Comment: Can this work>>>>>>>>>>> 
List<Object> combined = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Please refer to my answer, "If they do not implement a common interface, your List will have to be a list of Object"

Comment: I am getting error in calling methods from the combined arraylist eg.... combined.getName

Answer (score -1):

**First approach:**
If both the tables are related to each other (i.e. foreign key) then you can use join in LINQ query.

**Second approach:**
Create new list and one by one by casting it to a common class and add to newly created list.

Comment: There are not related so second approach may be possible but you have to please throw more light

Comment: Create a class i.e. NewClass, create extension method / mapper to map properties of both class to common class (NewClass), then cast first list and add to new list (i.e. List<NewClass>) and same for second.

Comment: sir, codes are not shown in comments. Please show snippets by modifying your answers